# How to get a unit-less result of the calc() function

Tags: css

I am using this calculation to get a fluid line-height in my webpage:

```
line-height: calc(1.42em + (1.55 - 1.42) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1080 - 300)));
```

And the math is working property except if I change the `font-size` of an specific section (since the `line-height` should be stated with a unit-less number in order to preserve the `font-size`/`line-height` ratio).

The question is: How do I get a unit-less result from this calculation?

I have tried removing the `em` and the `px` units, but that break the effect.

If I didn’t use this calculation, I would probably use something like:

```
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

I can get the `calc()` function to return 18px, for example. But how do I get the `calc()` function to return an unit-less result (like: 1.4) when I am using other multiple units inside it. Any way to convert the result in a unit-less number?

---

This is the whole CSS:

```
:root {
    --font: calc(16.2px + (18 - 16.2) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1080 - 300)));
    --verti: calc(1.42em + (1.55 - 1.42) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1080 - 300)));
}

html {
    font-family: "Georgia";
    font-size: var(--font);
    line-height: var(--verti);
}

.small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

This work great. But, the `line-height` of the class `.small` is to big. And I can either do another `calc()` function just for it, or have the preview `calc()` to return its value with a unit-less number.

Comment: Why do you need to use calc for this in the first place?

Comment: The real question is: how you will define this conversion? what is the result of `1px` without unit?

Comment: also why not using font-size with a similar calculation to keep both of them following the same logic?

Comment: I do not *need* it, but is adding a great effect. For example, if the viewport is wide (like in a computer), then the font-size gets bigger (I am using another calculation for the font-size too), that way I can get a fluid effect without media queries. Now, when the font get to a 20 px, the line-height seems a little to small (it is a visual effect, bigger font sometimes require bigger line-height. And the calc() function works perfectly, but I want a unitless number as the output, so i can work in any font-size (since the font-size change with the viewport size).

Comment: I update my question with the whole CSS code.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to get a unit-less value out of `calc()` if any of your inputs have units.

However in this particular case with `line-height` specifically, it should be noted that the unit-less value of `line-height: 1.4` is equivalent to `line-height: 140%`. Likewise `3.1` is equivalent to `310%` and etc. You should be able to modify your `calc()` equation to output the desired value with the `%` unit.

---

Edit: It seems inheritance behaves differently for unit-less and percent values, so use this approach with caution. It should be OK if you avoid specifying `line-height` on parent elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values

Answer (score 1):

By now it has been established than there is no CSS way to strip units from the result of a `calc(..)` that uses units.
This solution will show you a way to get the responsive scaling of the main `font-size` and `line-height` as you require,
as well as those of class `.small`. While using units...

**tl;dr => snippet**

```js
window.onload = window.onresize  = function() { showInfo() }

/*
    Get current a11y slider value and assign to custom variable.
*/
// References to page slider elements
const slider = document.getElementById('slider'); // a11y slider
const a11y   = document.getElementById('a11y');   // a11y slider value info

const sliderSetScale = () => {
    // Show current slider value
    a11y.innerHTML = slider.value;
    
    // Assign to CSS custom variable
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--a11y-scale', slider.value);

    // Show updated size values
    showInfo();
}

/*
    Show current font-size and line-height of demo elements.
*/

// References to page info elements
const nI     = document.getElementById('nInfo');  // normal info
const sI     = document.getElementById('sInfo');  // small info

const showInfo = () => {
    // Show current slider value
    a11y.innerHTML = slider.value;

    // Get current style values
    let nIst = getComputedStyle(nI);
    let sIst = getComputedStyle(sI);

    // Display current values (macro using 'backticks')
    nI.innerHTML = `fs: ${nIst.fontSize}, lh: ${nIst.lineHeight}`;
    sI.innerHTML = `fs: ${sIst.fontSize}, lh: ${sIst.lineHeight}`;
}
```

```css
:root {
    /* generic multiplier for a11y scaling of page elements */
    --a11y-scale: 1;

    /*
        Linear Equation y = mx + b
            point slope form: y − y1 = m(x − x1) 
                 substituted: y = y1 + (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1) × (x − x1)
    
        using points p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2):

        font-size   => p1(300, 16.2)        p2(1080, 18)
        line-height => p1(300, 16.2 * 1.42) p2(1080, 18 * 1.55)
    
        multiply endresult (y) with generic multiplier for element scaling
    */
    /* Filling in the above equation (2x use of 'px' otherwise the calc will fail) */
    --fs: calc( (16.2px        + (18.0 - 16.2)             / (1080 - 300) * (100vw - 300px)) * var(--a11y-scale) );
    --lh: calc( (16.2px * 1.42 + (18 * 1.55 - 16.2 * 1.42) / (1080 - 300) * (100vw - 300px)) * var(--a11y-scale) );
    /* NOTE: not simplified for demo purposes */
}

body {
    font-size  : var(--fs);
    line-height: var(--lh);
}
.normal {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: normal;
}

.small {
    font-size  : calc(0.8 * var(--fs));
    line-height: calc(0.8 * var(--lh));
}

.box {
    /* for easy centering of text */
    display: grid; place-items: center;

    /* create a responsive square using 'em' unit    */
    width : 6em; height: 6em; /* font size depending */
    /* main font size is a11y scaled, so is the box  */

    background-color: Gainsboro;
}

/* just eye-candy */
.wwrapper * { outline: 1px dashed }
input[type="range"] { width: 100% }

/*
    -----------------------------------------
    Linear Equation y=mx+b math in a Nutshell
    -----------------------------------------

    Using points p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2) where
        x1,y1 = the small viewport size (x1) where required small size is (y1)
        x2,y2 = the large viewport size (x2) where required large size is (y2)

        NOTE: the above will yield a rising slope, while using
              (y1) = large and (y2) = small will yield a falling slope,
              basically creating the inverse effect.

    on a 2D graph with
        x-axis = viewport size values
        y-axis = size attribute values

    and variable definitions
        y = the calculated size we want to use in CSS
        m = (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1) => delta Y / delta X => the 'change'
        x = either 100vh, vw, vmin or vmax, determined by viewport width/height dependency
        b = y1 − m × x1 => value of y when x = 0

    we use the equation 'point slope form'
        equation: y − y1 = m(x − x1)
        substituted: y = y1unit + (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1) × (x − x1unit)

        NOTE: in calc(..) attach a unit to the values where depicted
              or multiply with 1unit when using variables, otherwise
              the calc(..) will fail.

    to calculate any CSS size property value that has to responsively
    and fluidly scale relative to the current viewport width or height.
*/
```

```html
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895353/how-to-get-a-unit-less-result-of-the-calc-function -->

<label>a11y scale <span id="a11y"></span>
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0.5" max="3" step="0.01" value="1"
           oninput="sliderSetScale()">
</label>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="normal">this is unresponsive text for reference</div>

    <div>this is responsive text                      (<span id="nInfo"></span>)</div>
    <div class="small" >this is small responsive text (<span id="sInfo"></span>)</div>
    <br>
    <div class="box">box</div>
</div>
```

**Remember**

- You are using the 'point slope form' **y − y1 = m(x − x1)** of **Linear Equation y = mx + b** which requires
  the coordinates of two points on a straight line: **p1(x1,y1)** and **p2(x2,y2)**. The substituted equation for use in `calc(..)`: **y = y1 + (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1) × (x − x1)**.
- a unitless `line-height` is [OPTIONAL], any legal  unit is accepted
- 'em' unit is a multiplier depending on the elements current `font-size`
- a unitless `line-height` is a multiplier comparable to the 'em' unit, but *not* parent `font-size` dependend
- OP `line-height` is viewport depending and only *seems* parent `font-size` depending
- `.small line-height` cannot use `em` for `line-height` as it is not calculated

**Constraints** derived from the OP `calc(..)` equation:

- at a viewport width of 300px: main `font-size: 16.2px` and `line-height: 1.42em`
- at a viewport width of 1080px: main `font-size: 18px` and `line-height: 1.55em`
- class `.small` needs to be `0.8em` of both main `font-size` and `line-height`

Translating the constraints into equations, stripping the `em` unit (as it is just a multiplier):

1. `font-size` => points **p1(300, 16.2)** and **p2(1080, 18)**

- at a viewport width of 300px it should be `16.2px`
- at a viewport width of 1080px it should be `18px`
- Equation: `--fs: calc(16.2px + (18.0 - 16.2) / (1080 - 300) * (100vw - 300px))`

2. `line-height` => points **p1(300, 16.2 * 1.42)** and **p2(1080, 18 * 1.55)**

- at a viewport width of 300px it should be `16.2px * 1.42`
- at a viewport width of 1080px it should be `18px * 1.55`
- Equation `--lh: calc(16.2px * 1.42 + (18 * 1.55 - 16.2 * 1.42) / (1080 - 300) * (100vw - 300px))`

**As we now** have base values, we can use those to define all required font sizes and line height for our elements.

**E.g.** for `.small` we now can use `font-size: calc(0.8 * var(--fs))` and `line-height: calc(0.8 * var(--fs))` as the *parent font size* is `--fs` and the *parent line height* is `--lh`.

**Drawback** with this method we can no longer use the `em` unit when we need *calculated* responsive sizes. Simple `font-size` dependency using `em` is still possible (see `.box` in the snippet).

**BONUS**

I introduced custom variable `--a11y-scale` in the snippet above showcasing how to use a *generic element multiplier* to scale elements for accessibility purposes. It simply multiplies the result of equation with a `range slider` value. Basically showing how to combine *calculated* and *manual* scaling.

In the remainder of the CSS you can find a summary of the Linear Math.