# Change opacity depending on viewport size

Tags: css, css-calc

I'm trying to change element's opacity based on how wide the browser's window is in a continuous manner. Ideally, I would like to get a unit-less value from `calc` by dividing current viewport's width by some constant, like this:

```css
opacity: clamp(0.5, calc(100vw / 1000px), 1);
```

but `calc` doesn't allow dividing by a unit. Is there any other way to achieve this in CSS?

Comment: Why can'y you write "calc(100vw / 1000)"?

Comment: As you've discovered, you can't get a unit-less value here that will make any sense to the `opacity` property. You *most likely* will need to rely on JS for this. I could be wrong (and kind of hope I am), since this would be a cool effect using CSS only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a unit-less result of the calc() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895353/how-to-get-a-unit-less-result-of-the-calc-function)

Comment: @RiccardoLV `opacity` requires a unit-less value and `calc(100vw / 1000)` would return a length

Comment: @disinfor The answer posted there works for `line-height` because it accepts both a `<number>` and a `<length>` but `opacity` doesn't accept `<length>` unfortunately.

Comment: @JakubJanowski yeah, that's why I'm pointing it out. The answer there is: `calc` does not return a unit-less value, which is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you define some default opacities for different breakpoints using media queries I think you'd have to rely on js to achieve this. Seems like it is not possible to strip units in CSS unfortunately.

I was playing around with this in different ways and this was the closest behavior I could get:

> btw you can do basic math expressions without calc function as per docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp#parameters

```js
var r = document.querySelector(':root');

function log() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var opacity = getComputedStyle(document.body).opacity;
  r.style.setProperty('--vp-width', width);
  console.log(width, opacity);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', log);
log();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  opacity: clamp(0.5, var(--vp-width) / 1000, 1);
}

.content {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: This is definitely not the best way to change opacity dynamically using js!

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question asked, which is a "CSS solution." You probably didn't see it, but OP originally asked (before question edits): _"Is there any other way to achieve this in CSS or is this a task only for JavaScript?"_ My guess is OP knows the JS way to do it, but wanted a CSS only solution. And with JS, there's really no reason to use `clamp` or `calc` here, since you could set the opacity based on a division of window width only.

Comment: @disinfor yeah you're probably right and I'm aware of that so I understand if this gets downvoted. I still wanted to share my efforts towards finding a solution close to what's being asked even if it doesn't fully suffice, I think people (not only OP) might find it useful in a different context.

Comment: I don't think you'll get down voted! It does solve the issue (just not CSS only). It might be a bit complex, since you don't need to use `clamp` or `calc` with a CSS var.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely not the best way to change opacity dynamically using js